# wirtinger's presentation and torus knot are isomorphic?

Tags: knot-theory

I am trying to prove the injective property of group homomorphism between Wirtinger's Presentation of Trefoil Knot and by realizing the trefoil as a torus knot.

I define $ \phi   $ such that it takes *a* to $x_{2}x_{3}x_{2}$ and *b* to $ x_{2}x_{3}$.

any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know what you mean by $a,b,x_1,x_2,x_3$.  I'm going to guess $a^3=b^2$ for sake of discussion.

Did you already show it was a homomorphism?  In this case, it would mean show $\phi(a)^3=\phi(b)^2$.

Did you already show it was surjective?  You could do so by showing how to write each $x_i$ in terms of $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$.

For injectivity, you could show $\phi$ has a left inverse $\psi$ (a homomorphism such that $\psi\circ\phi=\mathrm{id})$.  Figure out where to send each $x_i$ so that $a=\psi(x_2x_3x_2)$ and $b=\psi(x_2x_3)$, and check the homomorphism property.

---

One may also proceed by [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations), of which the homomorphisms referred to above are just an ad hoc approximation.  Here is an image to demonstrate the calculation:

[image: Tietze transformations to convert Wirtinger presentation of trefoil to torus presentation]

Comment: sorry about not providing enough details. Yes, I have already shown homomorphism by showing it preserve relation, and also surjectivity that for every $x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$ there is $b^{-1}a$ and $a^{-1}b^{2}$ respectively. (I am considering $a^{2}=b^{3}$). About the left inverse, isn't much trivial if I consider $\psi$ send $x_{i}$ to elements what I already mentioned for surjectivity?

Comment: @Touseef Yep, there's not much to it, just make sure it is a homomorphism.  It's worth noting that all I'm saying is basically an ad hoc version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations

Comment: @Touseef Ok, I added how to do the Tietze transformations to illustrate.  Latent in it is an isomorphism that you may write out explicitly.